# Change HTML dropdown option font size

Tags: html, css

I have this simple HTML dropdown menu:

```
<select>
    <option style="font-size:50px;">Test</option>
</select>
```

I can't find a way to increase the font size of the option. The font-size property is being ignored for some reason. Is this a bug or what?

Thanks

Comment: Turn off the default OS styling...see details in my last edited answer.This will surely work.

Comment: In comments (and only in comments) you are saying that specifically sizes larger than 16px do not work. You need to specify the browser(s) tested and provide a reproduceable case. Some browsers do not let you style `option`, just `select`, but that’s a different issue (and well covered in old SO questions and answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should turn off the default OS styling with: `-webkit-appearance: none`;

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/KeFgP/)

Comment: it's not working on latest Firefox. Any other idea?

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried putting it on your `<select>` element?

```
<select style="font-size:50px;">
    <option>Test</option>
</select>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tCw8M/

Or with a stylesheet:

```
select {
   font-size: 50px;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tCw8M/2/

Comment: It doesn't work as well like this for some reason. The same problem. The tag responds to a maximum of `font-size: 16px;` Higher than that value is not responding

Comment: Hmm that is weird that it works up to a point. Have you tried both ways? The inline style attribute and an external stylesheet? Are you using any 3rd party libraries / plugins? The fiddles are working just fine so there has to be something on your end.

Comment: The fiddle demonstrates the problem :) The text size appears much smaller than the defined 50px;

Comment: Are you using some measurable way of checking that or are you just saying it doesn't *look* like 50px to you? Because on my end the text-size are looking fine. Also what browser/version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The font size option needs to be on the select tag, not the option tag:

```
<select style="font-size:50px;">
     <option >Test</option>
</select>
```

Whether you do it directly to the tag or in a css file selecting the tag is up to you.

Comment: It doesn't work as well like this for some reason. The same problem. The tag responds to a maximum of `font-size: 16px;` Higher than that value is not responding

Comment: Can you set any other element to a font size larger than 50px?

Comment: i dont necessarily need 50px. The tag doesn't work after 16px anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply the style in `select` not in `option` like:

```
select{
    font-size:50px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eR4QN/)

Comment: It doesn't work as well like this for some reason. The same problem. The tag responds to a maximum of `font-size: 16px;` Higher than that value is not responding

Comment: It works perfect. Maybe is something else. Can you provide a link?

Comment: Your link itself explains the problem :) The font size in the example fiddle can't by any means be 50px; 50px should be much more larger than this

Comment: Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/eR4QN/1/ and see there is no difference in size.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a stylesheet:

```
select{
font-size: 150px;

}
```

check out the example : http://jsfiddle.net/robcabrera/bx8R4/