# Change Select Option Element Font Family, Size etc

Tags: html, css, html-select

I am trying to change the font size of select option elements.

on my development server, my browser is firefox 52.0.2. here it shows fine. please see the below image:

[image]

Number-1: it get the font size from select style and works fine.

Number-2: it get the font size, and color from option element style and also works fine.

but when I test live on another computer where the firefox version is 57.0.1. it is showing like below image:

[image]

Note: you see? only color changes work but font size/family is not :(

this is the code I am trying:

```
         <Select name="GurdianRelation" id="GurdianRelation" style="font-family:scUniFont1; font-size:24px; line-height:normal; text-align:left; width:300px;">
                <option value="00" selected disabled hidden>অনুগ্রহপূর্বক নির্বাচন করুন</option>
                <option value="01" style="color:#F00; font-size:32px;">পিতা/মাতা</option>
                <option value="02">ভাই/বোন</option>
                <option value="03">দাদা/দাদী</option>
                <option value="04">নানা/নানী</option>
                <option value="05">চাচা/চাচী</option>
                <option value="06">ফুফু/ফুফা</option>
                <option value="07">মামা/মামী</option>
                <option value="08">খালা/খালু</option>
                <option value="09">অন্যান্য</option>
            </Select>
```

I have tried following so solution, none of them works:

1. [select option font-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830115/select-option-font-size)
2. [Change HTML dropdown option font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761965/change-html-dropdown-option-font-size)

so, I am out of ways now.. and expecting some help :)

thanks in advance
best regards

Comment: Have you imported the `font-family` to your website? post your css please

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj, thanks for your reply sir, yes i add that font family, and if you notice the selected option (not the highlighted one) in both image is same font family renders.

Comment: it will be better if you create a working snippet

Comment: FF57 doesn't allow for this.